# content security policy - unsafe inline and unsafe eval not working in moz and chrome

Tags: asp.net-mvc, security, iis

I have a mvc web application ,I have configure content security policy as

```
<add name="Content-Security-Policy" value="default-src 'self';script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' ;style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' ;img-src 'self';font-src 'self'  ; "/>
```

which work well in all browser including IE,CHROME,MOZILLA.

I am using lots of inline jquery/javascript code in cshtml page.

but my security team has fail my security of the web application and they wanted us to remove `'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'`

After i remove unsafe-inline and unsafe-eval application only work in IE ,But not working in chrome and mozilla. is there any work around to acheive the above without 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'

Answer (score 2):

You can try using `NWebSec` library to support you in the process of making your MVC application CSP compliant. See the documentation [here](https://docs.nwebsec.com/en/latest/).

You can take the help of `NWebSec TagHelpers` to make your scripts CSP compliant with nonce. See the information [here](https://docs.nwebsec.com/en/latest/nwebsec/NWebsec.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers.html).

A good read on this topic is [here](https://carra-lucia-ltd.co.uk/2018/01/10/content-security-policy-csp-for-asp-net-mvc/).

You can use a [ASP.Net MVC Boilerplate Template](https://rehansaeed.com/asp-net-mvc-boilerplate/) by Rehan Saeed to understand the CSP. It has the NWebSec already implemented.

Answer (score 1):

CSP is (as today 21/03/2018) not fully supported by IE (more information here https://caniuse.com/#search=csp).
Apparently your application is not CSP-compliant and this is why it does not run in a browser that implements CSP (like Chrome or Firefox).